# Insert method for a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, project

Alright so I am working on making a linked list and I have to insert each object I receive into the list and have them point to each other. Right now I have:

```
public void insert(Object o) {
   curr.setNext(new Link(curr.getItem(),curr.getNext()));
   curr.setItem(o);
}
```

I only seem to be throwing NullPointerExceptions though when I test this. This is my first test for it by the way:

```
public void testIfInsertMakesAList() {
    String a = "a";

    LList x = new LList();

    x.insert(a);

    String xExpected = "a";

    assertEquals("insert does not insert one object in a list", xExpected, x.get());
}
```

Any advice would be most helpful.

Comment: You might want to check if `curr` actually exists before you try and do anything with it.

Comment: right now curr is just a link and I use it to point through my list where I currently am. Should I set it to something?

Comment: Right now it's a `null`.  That should give you a clue as to where your **Null**PointerException is coming from

Comment: But isn't that what setting next would do? change it to pointing to somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, setting next would change it to point to something else.  The only problem is your `setNext` call refers to `next`.  Referring to something that doesn't exist (i.e.  trying to use it, as in `curr.getNext()`) is a bad thing and will invariably produce a NullPointerException

Comment: Should I set curr then to this new Link I am making?

Comment: Hard to tell.  You have not posted an [mcve], so anyone reading this question has no idea how your `Link` or `LList` (What's wrong with "LinkedList"?) classes are implemented.  Generally a list holds a reference to the "head" and "tail" links and each link holds at least a reference to the "next" link in the list.  An `insert` operation usually creates a new "head", so you might do something like `head = new Link(o, head)` (Or in your case `curr = new Link(o, curr)`)

Comment: If you insert 'a', 'b', 'c', each one should get inserted at the head so the items coming out 'c', 'b', 'a' is correct. It sounds like you're actually trying to `add` or `append` to the list

Comment: Ok so i think one of my problems with my code is I don't set head equal to anything but how do I connect head to the list cause it should be pointing to a fake link that connects to the start of the list I think? I'm not great at linked lists

Comment: You need to be very clear about what operations on your list are supposed to do and what the variables of an `LList` object are for.  If it helps, grab some physical objects and model the operations when you're designing them.  Your 'head' object is usually the first item in the list.  Inserting at the head replaces the head and sets the "next" object of the new head link to the old head. Similarly adding to the tail sets both the "next" link of the old tail and the "taiil" of the list to the new object.  Generally only lists that support the concept of a "current" insert position need "curr"

Comment: A "current position" is usually called a "cursor".  Not used a lot for lists